# Ansible /Jinja2 refer variable-key inside list-item being same dict

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

This `playbook.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vhosts[0].ssl_key_filename }}"
  vars:
    vhosts:
      - listen: "80"
        server_name: "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
        ssl_key_filename: "{{ server_name }}.key"
```

gives me the `undefined error` about `{{ server_name }}`.

How should I refer `server_name`?

...some more details for stupid so...
...some more details for stupid so...

Comment: Sorry, but could you please post the entire `playbook`? You have only added the `vars` definitions, which seem fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is an implementation bug in ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/8603#issuecomment-369917699).